# How to have fixed HeaderColumn width in ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

I want know how to have fixed HeaderColumn width in ListView.

```
private void listView_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    e.NewWidth = listView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width; 
}
```

But this method is not resolved.

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Did you hook up this event either by code or IDE?

Comment: The code works fine.  Did you associate it with the correct event?  Did you try debugging?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yes!  I checked hook with the listview event..

Comment: @ jason.kaisersmith yes. but It happens only on double-click times. It does not happen when it is dragged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent visual change during mouse move on _ColumnWidthChanging event. And remember previous width of sized column, and that it was user sizing event (not the designed code).
And on _ColumnWidthChanged event check if user sizing event and reset the width of column.

```
bool ColumnWidthChanging = false;
int ColumnWidthChangingWidth = -1;

private void listView1_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
{
  ColumnWidthChangingWidth = listView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
  ColumnWidthChanging = true;
  e.Cancel = true;
}

private void listView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (ColumnWidthChanging)
  {
    ColumnWidthChanging = false;
    listView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width = ColumnWidthChangingWidth;
  }
}
```